# Regex for matching linefeed with next character ignored

Tags: regex, notepad++, carriage-return, linefeed, control-characters

I am trying to select linefeed and remove them in a comma separated file via REGEX search in notepad++, the criteria for matching linefeed is that it should not followed the character "I" in the next line.

Example:-
[image]

Output should be:-
[image]

Comment: Your example and output don't appear in synch with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: don't use images as we can't copy past them

replace

```
\r\n(?!|)
```

with nothing

Note that I assume your are using windows linebreaks \r\n

Comment: the above regular expression works good with c#.net but is not working with the VB script.

Comment: can you also please explain about the regular expression? I dont understand what `?!|` means

Comment: Its working fine in VBscript too. All i was missing `MyRegexVariable.Global = True`

Comment: the  (?!|) fragment stands for negative lookahead and asserts that the pipe symbol can't follow. Note that lookaround does not match (its a zero width assertion) as very powerful technique. More info here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html